# What is the correct usage of Firefox ToggleButton?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing and debugging a Firefox Addon using the SDK (version 1.16, Firefox version 31).

I've been using the ToggleButton widget. I've noticed that when my extension is disabled in the `about:addons` menu, I see several 'TypeError: can't access dead object' message in toolbox console.  These messages show up when I activate, and open tabs.

The following is the simple code from the example that will demonstrate this issue:

```
var ui = require("sdk/ui");

var button = ui.ToggleButton({
    id: "my-button",
    label: "my button",
    icon: {
        "16": "./icon-16.png",
        "32": "./icon-32.png",
        "64": "./icon-64.png"
    },
    onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  require("sdk/tabs").open("https://www.mozilla.org/");
}

exports.onUnload = function (reason) {
    console.log("onUnload", reason);
    button.destroy();   
}
```

Do I need to do something differently (other than `destroy`) in the onUnload function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exports.onUnload` is rather *problematic*, i.e. there are a lot of bugs and a lot of things where it doesn't work correctly. Avoid it if possible (at least for now).

Fortunately, you don't actually need to destroy the button on unload: The SDK will do that automatically for you. The `.destroy()` instance method is meant for code that needs to destroy a button long before the add-on is unloaded (e.g. a "login" button that gets destroyed once the user logs in).

In your particular example, a `ToggleButton` is the wrong choice. Such a button is meant for things that are basically a checkbox (have two states, e.g. on and off).

Instead an [`ActionButton`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action) might be better suited, seeing that a click actually performs a certain action (opens some site in a new tab).

*Edit:* Turns out this is a bug in the SDK, that apparently got fixed already as it is not present.
In the current Firefox 31 release it is still present, however, and can be triggered with as little code as:

```
var ui = require("sdk/ui");

var button = ui.ActionButton({
    id: "my-button",
    label: "my button",
    icon: "./icon-16.png"
});
```

Since it is an SDK bug and does not really impact you while *running* your add-on, you should just ignore it for now and in future Firefox versions it isn't a problem anymore.

Comment: I made the change to use an ActionButton, but same error message `"can't access dead object"` occurs when the extension is disabled, and tabs are clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I thought it might be a bug, but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

It's a SDK bug, that is not related to buttons or `sdk/ui` modules, but more specifically to `event/dom` and `event/chrome`, and in certain degree with `system/events` module; that are required indirectly by buttons too – but not only, so you could face the same issue using different modules.

In short, the SDK adds some listeners in such modules but it doesn't perform a proper clean up once the add-on is disabled. Therefore when the events are emitted, they're trying to execute code that no longer exists.

The bugs are fixed in recent versions of Firefox, specifically in [bug 1001833](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1001833) and [bug 985332](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=985332) however that error, even if annoying, doesn't impact the functionality of your add-on, so don't worry.